# How to set the number of CPU cores shown to a pod

Tags: kubernetes

`containers[].resources.limits.cpu` can limit CPU resources for a pod like:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: cpu-demo-ctr
    image: vish/stress
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        cpu: "0.5"
```

I'd also like to set the number of CPU cores shown to a pod. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [documentation here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#cpu-units) the `1` cpu in is equivalent to:

- 1 AWS vCPU
- 1 GCP Core
- 1 Azure vCore
- 1 Hyperthread on a bare-metal Intel processor with Hyperthreading

So you can request a core using

```
cpu: "1"
```

or

```
cpu: "1000m"
```

But if you want to be more precise - you can allocate like 250m of a CPU:

```
cpu: "250m"
```

Lastly, if you need more than one cpu you could do:

```
cpu: "2"
```

Comment: It's not a number of CPU. I mean, I'd like to limit the number of CPU shown by `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood. What is the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: I dont think /proc/meminfo and /proc/cpuinfo are cgroup aware.  Maybe you can check cgroup info in /proc/self/cgroup of the container